# Equations governing softbody simulation parameters?

Tags: physics, soft-body

What are the equations that specify how settings like "Pull", "Push", "Damp", "Bending", etc— combined with mesh geometry and simulation state properties like edge length, face area and strain— are translated into edge stress/forces?

[image]

Comment: Blender uses [BulletPhysics2](https://github.com/blender/blender/tree/594f47ecd2d5367ca936cf6fc6ec8168c2b360d0/extern/bullet2) - unfortunately, the documentation is very sparse with a lot of dead (404) ends. You can start your research here: https://pybullet.org/ but I'd recommend going through the user manual of version 2.x, which you can find here: https://storage.googleapis.com/google-code-archive-source/v2/code.google.com/bullet/source-archive.zip (trunk/Bullet_User_Manual.pdf) - a short chapter *Soft Body Dynamics* won't tell you much but will get you started in investigating the source.